# A custom spock annotation to handle both applying and cleaning up metaclass changes?

Tags: groovy, annotations, spock

I want to modify the metaclass of a type *Bar* when I run unit tess using Spock and Groovy.

Currently I do the following:

```
@ConfineMetaClassChanges(Bar) -- this will cleanup the metaclass changes
class FooSpec extends Specification {

  def setupSpec() {
    BarHelper.setupMetaClass() -- this applies the metaclass changes
  }

  def "test Foo"() {
    given:
      def bar = createBar()
      def foo = createFoo(bar.x, bar.y)
    ...
  }

}

class BarHelper {
  static def setupMetaClass() {
    Bar.metaclass.x = { ... }
    Bar.metaclass.y = { ... }
  }
```

}

Having two operations to (a) change the metaclass and (b) clean up the metaclass changes is wasteful. I'm wondering if I can write an annotation that will do both, e.g :

```
@UsingBar -- internally, calls BarHelper.setupMetaClass(), and 
          -- also invokes @ConfineMetaClassChanges(Bar)
class FooSpec extends Specification {

  -- no need for setupSpec() method now

  def "test Foo"() {
    given:
      def bar = createBar()
      def foo = createFoo(bar.x, bar.y)
    ...
  }

}
```

With JUNit I can write a test rule or a class rule to do something similar, but I'm not sure of the best practice with Spock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a simpler solution: using groovy categories and the Spock `@Uses` annotation:

```
class BarCategory {
  static getX(Bar bar) { ... }
  static getY(Bar bar) { ... }
}

@Uses(BarCategory)
public class FooSpec extends Specification {

  def "test Foo"() {
    given:
      def bar = createBar()
      def foo = createFoo(bar.x, bar.y)
      ...
  }

}
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
def "test Foo"() {
  given:
    uses(BarCategory) {
      def bar = createBar()
      def foo = createFoo(bar.x, bar.y)
    }
    ...
```

}

And I don't need to worry about metaclass changes infecting other code.